# Dropdown menu on a multiline list

Tags: html, css

I have an example of my problem set up [here.](http://pastebin.me/82199f7237819c3c3065c5ae83170fcf)

I have had to set some li's to display: inline, so that they can occur on the same line, but now I need to add drop-down lists to them, and the drop down lists are happening on the other side of the page from where I would like them to. Do I have to position my original li's in a different manner?

Comment: perhaps you might make it easier for someone to help you?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it easier than by showing it to you.

Comment: Do you want the top level on the left or the right of the page?

Comment: The right. That's why the parent ul is aligned right.

Comment: Should have asked you if wanted top level on the same line, or are there supposed to be 2 levels, item 1 & 2 above item 3

Comment: Yes, in the case of the example, keeping item one and two above item three is a necessity. In the actual implementation, there will be three 'line's of list items, each with a nested list.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if you want to use the `:hover` class in anything other than an anchor tag, forget getting it to work in IE6 and make sure you have the correct `DOCTYPE` for the other browsers.

Try replacing the relevant parts of your CSS with this:

```
li
{
    display: inline;
}

ul.level_1 li
{
    position: relative;
}

ul.level_1 ul
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

li:hover ul
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Basically hides the sub-level list until you hover over the parent list item node.

Setting the parent list item nodes as `position:relative` means that if you set any child nodes within as `position:absolute` it will be set relative not to the browser window but to the parent list item. This will have them show up directly underneath the list item you're hovering over and not on the other side of the window.

The width was added to have the sub-level list display as a line instead of a column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to move the top menu to the left, or the submenus to the right, so I'll propose a solution either way.

If you want the main menu items to appear on the left,  then you need to remove or change the `text-align: right` in your `body` css.

If you want the submenus to appear on the right side, then because your `<ul>`s are absolutely positioned, you should change this rule:

```
    li:hover ul
    {
        left: auto;
    }
```

to this:

```
    li:hover ul
    {
        right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I am attempting to move the li:hover ul to the right. BUT: All this is in an margin:auto div, so right: 0 will not work. I need the nested lists to show up directly under the parent hovered over li.